# How to make a math function with equal sign in blender?

Tags: node-editor, mathematics

I was trying to make a circle . I tried to use this function (x*x)+(y*y)=a.
Making (x*x)+(y*y) was easy  but how i should go about making =a part  in blender shader editor? (also it would be great if someone can explain me why changing "a" change the size of the circle)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations

Comment: I think there is no "=" in shader nodes because if equal the result won't have any thickness and so won't be visible. Use "less than" and "greater than" instead. But in 2.82 there is now a "Compare" math node option which can take a tolerance to the comparison..